# Long running ruby code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, background

How to prevent long running code in Rails application

Block of Rails code taking more time to process. How to daemonize block of code or run it in background.

Comment: Take a look at the sidekiq gem http://mperham.github.io/sidekiq/ there is also a Railscast about it http://railscasts.com/episodes/366-sidekiq

Answer (score 0):

I answered here - [How to run ruby script asynchronous from rails controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16896393/how-to-run-ruby-script-asynchronous-from-rails-controller/16896482#16896482)

Anyway, you can choose preferred for your tasks: https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/Background_Jobs